# "Error loading tab :(" when trying to append more than 3 html strings to the DOM

Tags: jquery, getjson

*Despite the error, my problem has nothing to do with tabs*

I am using jQuery to get a pretty large JSON file (almost 0.5 mb) and inserting a bunch of html from it into the DOM. This still works:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('results.json', function(data){
    var result = $('<ul>');
    var resultEl = $('#results');
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      result.append(unescape(data[i].html));
    }
    result.appendTo(resultEl);
  });
});
```

I can insert two html parts fine, but when I try to insert three items this gets added to the DOM:

```
<section id="loading-tab" class="tab-content clearfix hidden">
  <h2 class="visuallyhidden">Loading</h2>
  <p>Loading...</p>
</section>
<section id="error-tab" class="tab-content clearfix hidden">
  <h2 class="visuallyhidden">Error</h2>
  <p>Error loading tab :(</p>
</section>
```

[Here](http://lab.askmike.org/stuff/wtf.html) is a link where I try to insert 2 items (and it still works) and [here](http://lab.askmike.org/stuff/wtf2.html) is a link where I try to loop to 3 and everything breaks.

Comment: It appears to be the data of the third element. I tried manually appending data[2] (without the others inserted) and it gave me the tab error. The html appears to unescape fine, though, so I'm not sure what about it is causing it.

Comment: the appending works fine, errors came straight out of my source.  I was pulling my hair out, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third JSON element has a `script` tag that runs the following (the string of `document.write` is broken out for ease of reading)

```
<script>
document.write('
    <section id="loading-tab" class="tab-content clearfix hidden">
        <h2 class="visuallyhidden">Loading</h2>
        <p>Loading...<\/p>
    <\/section>
    <section id="error-tab" class="tab-content clearfix hidden">
        <h2 class="visuallyhidden">Error<\/h2>
        <p>Error loading tab :(<\/p>
    <\/section>');
</script>
```

Which is writing the `Error loading tab :(` to the page. Clean up the data and you should be good to go.